# scrape website using nodejs cheerio deep nested element tags

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape text from a website but can't seem to extract anything.

below is the structure and code.

[image]

My code:

```
const rp = require("request-promise");
const $ = require("cheerio");
const url = "xx";

rp(url)
  .then(function(html) {
    //success!
    let token = "ce-bodytext";
    console.log($(token, response).length);
    console.log($(token, html)).text;
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
  });
```

While I just need the text, there was no id to the  tag. 
Also, I was hoping `ce-bodytext` would extract all values in order

but all I get is empty output.

```
{}
```

How do I just extract the text as shown in the image?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
let token = ".ce-bodytext>p>strong>font>font";
console.log($(token, html).text());
```

Answer (score 1):

`ce-bodytext` is a `class`, you forgot to add `.` before it :

```
const token = '.ce-bodytext';
```

It will at least fix the empty output.