# NodeJS scrape data deep withing an element tree

Tags: html, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I have worked with some projects in the past where I used NodeJS in order to read my CPU's temperature so I would say I understand a bit how NodeJS works. Then I was interested in reading data from websites which do not have an API and I found my way to NodeJS again for scraping data.

**Guide** (which I tried to follow and implement on my own project): https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-scraping-with-node-js-daa2027dcd3/

In the guide they use the following code snippet:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const $ = require('cheerio');
const url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Presidents_of_the_United_States';

rp(url)
  .then(function(html){
    //success!
    console.log($('big > a', html).length);
    console.log($('big > a', html));
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    //handle error
  });
```

In order to scrape the elements in the Big tag which resulted in 45 elements (45 presidents of USA).

The html structure I am working with looks something like:

**My html**

```
...

<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <dl class="(VERY LONG NAME)">
                <dt><span>info</span></dt>
                ...
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

...
```

**...** - extra code which I am not sure if it is needed.

**VERY LONG NAME** - has a lot of classes.

Naturally I tried to copy this code by changing big > a to the path in my HTML which is where I believe I might have missunderstood how to correctly set up a path. The following code is the code I tried to implement.

**My code**

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const $ = require ('cheerio');
const url = 'URLPATH';

rp(url)
  .then(function(html){
    //success!
    let token = ".content > .row > .column > dl > dt";

    console.log($(token, html).length);

  })
  .catch(function(err){
      console.log("FAILURE");
    //handle error
  });
```

I added **Token** after looking at: [scrape website using nodejs cheerio deep nested element tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053478/scrape-website-using-nodejs-cheerio-deep-nested-element-tags) and I tried different ways of creating my path such as: `"div[class="content"] > div[class="row"] > ..."`, the one above.

**My questions are**:

- Have I implemented the correct path and if so is there a reason it is
  returning 0 elements? Should I look at it in another way?
- If I have not implemented the correct path, how can I do so and what
  could happen if there are two identical paths? Do I just receive all
  the elements from all the paths?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(`
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <dl class="(VERY LONG NAME)">
                <dt><span>info</span></dt>
                ...
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
`)
console.log($(".content > .row > .column > dl > dt").length)
```

You should see 1.

What does that tell us? Your selector is fine but your html is not what you think it is.

Comment: So @pguardiario, what do you mean when you say my html is not what I think it is? Is the selector wrong if we would have a bigger tree. For example if the content div would be in another div it would not work? Then I might have missunderstood the guide.

Comment: I'm saying examine that html, it could be empty for all you know.